# customize the text in html output of DT table

Tags: r

I want to keep the particular text in summary as BOLD text . for example in below summary i want to make Target in third column as BOLD

```
df <- mtcars[1:6,1:5]
df <- df %>%mutate(cyl = case_when(
   cyl > 6 ~ "Target",
   cyl > 4 ~ "Goal",
   cyl > 1 ~ "None"
   
  
))
df <- datatable(df)
df %>% formatPercentage(4:5) %>%
  formatStyle(c(2:5),
              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add bold tag (`<b>`) around the word which we want as bold and use it with `escape = FALSE` in `datatable` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

df <- mtcars[1:6,1:5]
df <- df %>%mutate(cyl = case_when(
  cyl > 6 ~ "<b>Target</b>",
  cyl > 4 ~ "Goal",
  cyl > 1 ~ "None"
))

df %>% 
  datatable(escape = FALSE) %>%
  formatPercentage(4:5) %>%
  formatStyle(c(2:5),
              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

[image]

Comment: please explain , how does this work...?? how we can use it

Comment: I added some explanation around the code.